# CSS not being applied in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to include CSS with my Laravel 4 project.  The css is in a folder called 'assets' within the 'public' folder.

In my view, I am calling the CSS:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    {{ HTML::style('../assets/CSS/style.css') }}
</head>

<body>
    <div class="banner-image"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the CSS file, banner-image is defined as:

```
.banner-image{background:transparent url('../assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;background-size:cover; height:800px; min-width: 1200px;}
```

The page is loading fine, and checking the source, the path is correct for the CSS, but the CSS is not being applied.  Do you know what the issue may be?

Comment: Please try to not use ../ , try to start from the root. I guess it should be /assets/CSS/style.css and /assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg .

Comment: This still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your assets folder is in the root of your `/public` folder. Try this:

```
{{ HTML::style('/assets/CSS/style.css') }}

.banner-image{background:transparent url('/assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```